# In Facebook share, how to control the website name/link shared beside the time ago?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

[image]

That page was shared from my website via Facebook share button, but as per highlighted link in red, it's showing an incorrect text so I wanted to be able to control it (and the link address too if possible).

I viewed the source of my web page, it showed *link.net* from my canonical link in `<head>`, I thought I can control it there but no.

Thought it's derived from my dev site www.mydevsite.01.myname.link.net but I can't confirm. Also because I have seen some shares not having the "link.net" at all (dunno how it's called but it's the link beside the time ago).

So I guessed I can control it in meta tags but it seemed it's not `<meta property="og:site_url" content="website" />` either.

Comment: That is the name of the app I believe

Comment: how do you set the name of the app?

Comment: got it - its the name of the app indeed. https://graph.facebook.com/[my_app_id]

Comment: The name you change at developers.facebook.com/apps